# await Task.Delay takes longer than expected

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I wrote a multithreaded app which uses async/await extensively. It is supposed to download some stuff at a scheduled time. To achieve that, it uses 'await Task.Delay'. Sometimes it sends thousands requests every minute.

It works as expected, but sometimes my program needs to log something big. When it does, it serializes many objects and saves them to a file. During that time, I noticed that my scheduled tasks are executed too late. I've put all the logging to a separate thread with the lowest priority and the problem doesn't occur that often anymore, but it still happens. The things is, I want to know when it happens and in order to know that I have to use something like that:

```
var delayTestDate = DateTime.Now;
await Task.Delay(5000);
if((DateTime.Now - delayTestDate).TotalMilliseconds > 6000/*delays up to 1 second are tolerated*/) Console.WriteLine("The task has been delayed!");
```

Moreover, I have found that 'Task.Run', which I also use, can also cause delays. To monitor that, I have to use even more ugly code:

```
var delayTestDate = DateTime.Now;
await Task.Run(() =>
{
  if((DateTime.Now - delayTestDate).TotalMilliseconds > 1000/*delays up to 1 second are tolerated*/) Console.WriteLine("The task has been delayed!");
  //do some stuff
  delayTestDate = DateTime.Now;
});
if((DateTime.Now - delayTestDate).TotalMilliseconds > 1000/*delays up to 1 second are tolerated*/) Console.WriteLine("The task has been delayed!");
```

I have to use it before and after every await and Task.Run and inside every async function, which is ugly and inconvenient. I can't put it into a separate function, since it would have to be async and I would have to await it anyway. Does anybody have an idea of a more elegant solution?

EDIT:

Some information I provided in the comments:

As @YuvalItzchakov noticed, the problem may be caused by Thread Pool starvation. That's why I used `System.Threading.Thread` to take care of the logging outside of the Thread Pool, but as I said, the problem still sometimes occur.

I have a processor with four cores and by subtracting results of `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` from `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` I get 0 busy worker threads and 1-2 busy completion port threads. `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count` usually returns about 30. It's a Windows Forms app and although it only has a tray icon with a menu, it starts with 11 threads. When it gets to sending thousands requests per minute, it quickly gets up to 30.

As @Noseratio suggested, I tried to play with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` and `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`, but it didn't even change the numbers of busy threads mentioned above.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know about every delay? Isn't there some other metric that you could look at instead?

Comment: @svick There are events scheduled at certain times, which I need to monitor. So no, time is my only point of reference.

Comment: Exactly same issue i'm also facing

Answer (score 3):

When you execute Task.Run it uses Thread Pool threads to execute those tasks. When you have long running tasks, you are causing starvation to the Thread Pool, since its resources are currently occupied with long running tasks.

2 Suggestions:

1. When running long running tasks, make sure to use Task.Factory.Startnew with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, which will trigger a new thread creation. You must be cautious here as well, as spinning too many new threads will cause excessive context switches which will cause your app to slow down
2. Use true async where you have to do IO Bound work, use apis that support the TAP such as HttpClient and Stream, which wont cause a new thread to execute blocking work.

Comment: I know about Thread Pool starvation. What surprises me is that it still occurs when I run the logging job in a separate thread which is not controlled by the Thread Pool (I simply use System.Threading.Thread). Also, 'ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads' shows that only 1 thread is busy. As for your other suggestions, the tasks aren't long running and I use true async everywhere I can.

Comment: How many cores does the machine you are running your code on have?

Comment: Four cores. `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count` usually returns about 30 and to be more precise, `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` returns 0 busy worker threads and 1-2 busy completion port threads, which is kind of strange.

Comment: So you have around 35 threads spinning simultaneously on 4 cores? why so many? it really makes sense that you would feel your tasks are starting "late" because of massive context switches.

Comment: It's a Windows Forms app, although it only has a tray icon with a menu. It starts with 11 threads, but when it gets to sending thousands requests per minute, it quickly gets up to 30. I actually thought that it wasn't that much.

Comment: I suggest you use a performance benchmark tool and stress out your app a bit so you can really dig up and see whats going on. If you use Visual Studio 2013 you can use the built-in performance diagnostics, works great.

Answer (score 2):

There are overheads in async/await, as well as the tasks themselves being executed at a lower priority. If you need something to happen reliably at an accurate interval, async/await / TPL is not the interface to use.

Try creating an independent background thread that loops until it is scheduled to do work. This way you can control the priority and timing directly without going through TPL / async.

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(BackgroundWork);
DateTime nextInterval = DateTime.Now;

public void BackgroundWork()
{
    if(DateTime.Now > nextInterval){
        DoWork();
        nextInterval = nextInterval.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,10)); // 10 seconds
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Adjust the Sleep(..) and interval values as needed.

Comment: Despite the fact that running `Thread.Sleep` blocks an entire thread doing nothing while `Task.Delay` is much more scalable.

Comment: @nikeee But that scalability also has a cost, which is pretty much what this question is about.

Comment: I don't like this solution too much, since I'd really like to use async/await/TPL. It's easier to code and many .NET Framework objects support it. But if nothing else comes up, I will mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: -1 Has very little advantage over doing this using TPL, async. Would recommend instead to use `await Task.Wait(100).ConfigureAwait(false)` instead.

Comment: A LOT of overhead apparently. just having `Task.Delay(1);` (and nothing else) in a for loop going over 1000 iterations, it takes 14 seconds for me, instead of one-ish

Answer (score 2):

I think you're experiencing the situation described by Joe Duffy in his ["CLR thread pool injection, stuttering problems"](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/07/08/clr-thread-pool-injection-stuttering-problems/) blog post:

> One silly thing our thread pool currently does has to do with how it
>   creates new threads. Namely, it severely throttles creation of new
>   threads once you surpass the “minimum” number of threads, which, by
>   default, is the number of CPUs on the machine. We limit ourselves to
>   at most one new thread per 500ms once we reach or surpass this number.

One solution might be to explicitly increase the minimum number of thread pool threads before making any use of TPL, e.g.:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(workerThreads: 200, completionPortThreads: 200);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads: 100, completionPortThreads: 100);
```

Try playing with these numbers and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I played with those a little, but no matter which numbers I used, `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` returned 0 busy worker threads and 1-2 busy completion port threads.

Comment: @humanista, what about `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count` ? Does it show a realistic number nearly matching those requested with `SetMinThreads`?

Comment: It returns about 30 threads. I've just updated the OP, so please read it for the details.

Comment: @humanista, try also `await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false)`. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere you don't need the UI thread context after continuation. Does it change anything? Also, can you come up with a piece of code we can use to repro the problem?