# Why is Task.WhenAny so slow when called many times against the same TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: .net, performance, async-await, task-parallel-library

If a class has a member `TaskCompletionSource<TResult> m_tcs` with a long lifetime, and if Task.WhenAny is called with `m_tcs.Task` as one of its arguments, performance seems to degrade exponentially when the number of calls surpasses 50,000 calls or so.

Why is it so slow in this case? Might there be an alternative that operates faster but without using 4x more memory?

My thought is that `Task.WhenAny` is likely adding and removing so many continuations to and from `m_tcs.Task` and somewhere in there it results in a complexity of O(N²).

I found a more performant alternative by wrapping the TCS in an async function that awaits `m_tcs.Task`. It uses about 4x the memory but runs *much* faster beyond 20,000 iterations.

Sample code below (for accurate results, compile and run the .exe directly without the debugger attached). Note that `WhenAnyMemberTcsDirect` has the performance issue, `WhenAnyMemberTcsIndirect` is the faster alternative, and `WhenAnyLocalTcs` is a baseline for comparison:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class WithTcs
{
    // long-lived TaskCompletionSource
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> m_tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // this has performance issues for large N - O(N^2)
    public async Task WhenAnyMemberTcsDirectAsync(Task task)
    {
        await await Task.WhenAny(task, m_tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    // performs faster - O(N), but uses 4x memory
    public async Task WhenAnyMemberTcsIndirectAsync(Task task)
    {
        await await Task.WhenAny(task, AwaitTcsTaskAsync(m_tcs)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task<TResult> AwaitTcsTaskAsync<TResult>(TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs)
    {
        return await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    // baseline for comparison using short-lived TCS
    public async Task WhenAnyLocalTcsAsync(Task task)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        await await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        show_warning_if_debugger_attached();

        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        show_warning_if_debugger_attached();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        const int n = 100000;

        Console.WriteLine("Running Task.WhenAny tests ({0:#,0} iterations)", n);
        Console.WriteLine();

        await WhenAnyLocalTcs(n).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await WhenAnyMemberTcsIndirect(n).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await WhenAnyMemberTcsDirect(n).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    static Task WhenAnyLocalTcs(int n)
    {
        Func<WithTcs, Task, Task> function =
            (instance, task) => instance.WhenAnyLocalTcsAsync(task);

        return RunTestAsync(n, function);
    }

    static Task WhenAnyMemberTcsIndirect(int n)
    {
        Func<WithTcs, Task, Task> function =
            (instance, task) => instance.WhenAnyMemberTcsIndirectAsync(task);

        return RunTestAsync(n, function);
    }

    static Task WhenAnyMemberTcsDirect(int n)
    {
        Func<WithTcs, Task, Task> function =
            (instance, task) => instance.WhenAnyMemberTcsDirectAsync(task);

        return RunTestAsync(n, function);
    }

    static async Task RunTestAsync(int n, Func<WithTcs, Task, Task> function, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);

        var tasks = new Task[n];
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var startBytes = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        sw.Start();

        var instance = new WithTcs();
        var step = n / 78;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var iTemp = i;
            Task primaryTask = Task.Run(() => { if (iTemp % step == 0) Console.Write("."); });
            tasks[i] = function(instance, primaryTask);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var endBytes = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        sw.Stop();
        GC.KeepAlive(instance);
        GC.KeepAlive(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine("  Time: {0,7:#,0} ms, Memory: {1,10:#,0} bytes", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, endBytes - startBytes);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void show_warning_if_debugger_attached()
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            Console.WriteLine("WARNING: running with the debugger attached may result in inaccurate results\r\n".ToUpper());
    }
}
```

Sample results:

```
Iterations | WhenAny* Method   | Time (ms) | Memory (bytes)
---------: | ----------------- | --------: | -------------:
     1,000 | LocalTcs          |        21 |         58,248
     1,000 | MemberTcsIndirect |        54 |        217,268
     1,000 | MemberTcsDirect   |        21 |         52,496
    10,000 | LocalTcs          |        91 |        545,836
    10,000 | MemberTcsIndirect |        98 |      2,141,836
    10,000 | MemberTcsDirect   |       140 |        545,640
   100,000 | LocalTcs          |       210 |      4,898,512
   100,000 | MemberTcsIndirect |       502 |     21,426,316
   100,000 | MemberTcsDirect   |    14,090 |      5,085,396
   200,000 | LocalTcs          |       366 |      9,630,872
   200,000 | MemberTcsIndirect |       659 |     41,450,916
   200,000 | MemberTcsDirect   |    42,599 |     10,069,248
   500,000 | LocalTcs          |       808 |     23,670,492
   500,000 | MemberTcsIndirect |     1,906 |     97,339,192
   500,000 | MemberTcsDirect   |   288,373 |     24,968,436
 1,000,000 | LocalTcs          |     1,642 |     47,272,744
 1,000,000 | MemberTcsIndirect |     3,149 |    200,480,888
 1,000,000 | MemberTcsDirect   | 1,268,030 |     48,064,772
```

Note: targeting .NET 4.6.2 Release (Any CPU), tested on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit, Intel Core i7-4770.

Comment: Just to note, I can recreate the same behavior on .NET 4.7 and on a netcoreapp1.1 project on a windows 10 creators edition machine too.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the behavior is consistent in different environments.

Comment: What is the execution environment for that? Is there a synchronization context? @ScottChamberlain, was there any in your case?

Comment: @Noseratio My initial tests were in a console application with no synchronization context. I just attempted re-running the tests in a WinForms app with a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and removing every single `ConfigureAwait` call, and while the results appear closer at 100K iterations, `WhenAnyMemberTcsDirect` took 46 seconds at 500K iterations, which is a lot better than 288 seconds, but a lot slower than 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @Noseratio While it doesn't completely fix performance, I wonder why using a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and continuing on the captured synchronization context makes such a big difference?

Comment: @MikeHenry, your test model is most likely affected by [the thread pool stuttering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23176544/1768303), try increasing and fixing the size of the thread pool (e.g, `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(100, 100); ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);`). Does it change the results for the console app?

Comment: As to `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, I suspect it somewhat improved the results because all continuations are posted to the same thread (the main UI thread), so ThreadPool might be stuttering less. 
For a console app without s/c though, I'm still confused as to why using `tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` vs `tcs.Task` makes such a big difference. I wonder if has something to do with extensive GC. Try preventing GC for the scope of the test (`GC.TryStartNoGCRegion`/`GC.EndNoGCRegion`), see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Noseratio, thanks for your suggestions. Setting min/max threads for the thread pool did indeed improve performance of the console app so it's close to the performance of WhenAnyMemberTcsDirect in WinForms. (68 seconds at 500K iterations with ConfigureAwait(false) and 73 seconds at 500K iterations with ConfigureAwait(true))

Comment: @Noseratio The ThreadPool stuttering does sound like it's somewhat of a factor. Using GC.{TryStart|End}NoGCRegion seemed to hinder performance slightly, but then my tests were already using GC.KeepAlive. Also, I had to target x64 instead of Any CPU to even use NoGCRegion with this many iterations.

Comment: @MikeHenry, one other thing you could try is to use `ValueTask<T>` instead of `Task<T>` where possible.

Comment: @Noseratio I didn't even know about `ValueTask<T>`, I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that appears to run both fast (O(N) time) and in approx. the same memory space, by using a member `CancellationTokenSource m_cts` alongside the `TaskCompletionSource`. Any former calls to set `m_tcs` canceled/faulted/result would need to be accompanied by `m_cts.Cancel()`. This of course could be abstracted.

The solution:

```
public class WithTcs
{
    // ... same as above, plus below

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource m_cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public async Task WhenAnyMemberCtsAsync(Task task)
    {
        var ct = m_cts.Token;
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        using (ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetFrom(m_tcs)))
            await await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public static class TcsExtensions
{
    public static bool TrySetFrom<TResult>(this TaskCompletionSource<TResult> dest, TaskCompletionSource<TResult> source)
    {
        switch (source.Task.Status)
        {
            case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                return dest.TrySetCanceled();
            case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                return dest.TrySetException(source.Task.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                return dest.TrySetResult(source.Task.Result);
            default:
                return false; // TCS has not yet completed
        }
    }
}
```

This answers the question of if there's a fast alternative that is memory efficient. I'm still curious about what's happening behind the scenes of `WhenAnyMemberTcsDirect` to cause the O(N²) issue.