# Async/await performance

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on performance optimization of the program which widely uses async/await feature. Generally speaking it downloads thousands of json documents through HTTP in parallel, parses them and builds some response using this data. We experience some issues with performance, when we handle many requests simultaneously (e.g. download 1000 jsons), we can see that a simple HTTP request can take a few minutes.

I wrote a small console app to test it on a simplified example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(IoBoundWork);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task IoBoundWork()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

And I can see similar behavior here:

[image]

The question is why "await Task.Delay(1000)" eventually takes 23 sec.

Comment: You are testing the wrong thing. how are you making the http calls? Also is the actual program a console application?

Comment: We have one shared HttpClient and use GetStringAsync()

Comment: if I replace Task.Delay with await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://someurl.com"); I have similar results

Comment: Could your issue be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171696/await-task-delay-takes-longer-than-expected)?

Comment: Looks similar, but I tried to use SetMinThreads and it didn't see the big difference

Comment: Also those tasks run on the same thread context. Try with `Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: @Jimi: No, there's no synchronization context here - the tasks are all running on the thread pool. `Task.Run` executes the task on the thread pool.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes, in the context of this test (when I wrote that, the comment where he states he's using `await httpClient.GetStringAsync()` was _hidden_). In my experience, if the called async method is the actual worker (it doesn't call another async worker method and awaits for it) those threads tend to not overlap. Like they were synchronous, more if their execution time tends to 0.

Comment: @Jimi: That wasn't at all clear from your comment - and still depends on what the original context is, which we don't have information on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Task.Delay` isn't broken, but you're performing 100,000 tasks which each take some time. It's the call to `Console.WriteLine` that is causing the problem in this particular case. Each call is cheap, but they're accessing a shared resource, so they aren't very highly parallelizable.

If you remove the call to `Console.WriteLine`, all the tasks complete very quickly. I changed your code to return the elapsed time that each task observes, and then print just a single line of output at the end - the maximum observed time. On my computer, without any `Console.WriteLine` call, I see output of about 1.16 seconds, showing very little inefficiency:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50000, 50000);
        var tasks = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 100000)
            .Select(_ => Task.Run(IoBoundWork))
            .ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        var maxTime = tasks.Max(t => t.Result);
        Console.WriteLine($"Max: {maxTime}");
    }

    private static async Task<double> IoBoundWork()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

You can then modify `IoBoundWork` to do different tasks, and see the effect. Examples of work to try:

- CPU work (do something actively "hard" for the CPU, but briefly)
- Synchronous sleeping (so the thread is blocked, but the CPU isn't)
- Synchronous IO which *doesn't* have any shared bottlenecks (although that's generally hard, given that the disk or network is likely to end up being a shared resource bottleneck even if you're writing to different files etc)
- Synchronous IO with a shared bottleneck such as `Console.WriteLine`
- Asynchronous IO (`await foo.WriteAsync(...)` etc)

You can also try removing the call to `Task.Delay(1000)` or changing it. I found that by removing it entirely, the result was very small - whereas replacing it with `Task.Yield` was very similar to `Task.Delay`. It's worth remembering that as soon as your async method has to actually "pause" you're effectively doubling the task scheduling problem - instead of scheduling 100,000 operations, you're scheduling 200,000.

You'll see a different pattern in each case. Fundamentally, you're starting 100,000 tasks, asking them all to wait for a second, then asking them all to do something. That causes issues in terms of continuation scheduling that's async/await specific, but also plain resource management of "Performing 100,000 tasks each of which needs to write to the console is going to take a while."

Comment: Curious. Console redirection to a file on disk is usually faster for me than without redirection.

Comment: @Dai: Yes, that's what I've shown too. (With the redirection, the output is fast. Without it, it's slow.)

Comment: But Elapsed of watch in OP code is retrieved before call to WriteLine, so it does not by itself measure console write perfomance. I'm not saying that problem is not related to Console.WriteLine though.

Comment: @Evk: Ah, that's a good point. I'm about to have lunch so can't investigate further - I strongly suspect that the problem is that the thread pool is filled with threads which *are* blocked on Console.WriteLine.

Comment: Yes that's what I think the problem is too.

Comment: In our original app we actually have a mixture of CPU-bound and IO-bound work, e.g. before making HTTP requests we parse protobuf requests, which contain urls to download, parse jsons, compress and decompress data. To be honest I suspect that this is a real issue, because threads of thread pol are blocked by this work.

Comment: @olegk: Well without knowing what your real code is doing, it's very hard to pinpoint the problem. But my experiments suggest that the problem *isn't* in `Task.Delay`. Perhaps your code is doing something else which has a bottleneck like `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: @Evk: Edited a lot - see if that's any better.

Comment: Yes, I understand, anyway many thanks for the help. Later I will try to post an example which will be closer to what our app is doing.

Comment: I wonder if increasing min thread pool threads to some huge value has significant effect on OP code? So if observed delay is mostly because thread pool waits for 1 second before creating new thread while all current threads are blocked by WriteLine or not? I'm  on mobile and cannot test myself at the moment.

Comment: @Evk: Not in what I've currently observed, no. My observations are that there aren't actually very many threads started - and that changing the minimum number doesn't improve things. I suspect the interaction between the task scheduler and the thread pool is at work here, but i don't know enough about that to try to improve things :(

Comment: I found that thread pool in CLR 4 is more sophisticated than in CLR 2. It's not as simple as "wait for 500ms if no threads available and number of busy threads > minimum, then add new thread". Here is an article that goes into detail: http://mattwarren.org/2017/04/13/The-CLR-Thread-Pool-Thread-Injection-Algorithm/. But in short, it tries to maximize throughput while using as few threads as possible. If you change OP code to `Task.Factory.StartNew(IoBoundWork, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);` - all times will be around 1s, but it will take much longer overall.

Comment: @Evk: Yes, that will start 100,000 threads - but it will still schedule 100,000 continuations on the thread pool. (My understanding, anyway...)

Comment: Yes, maybe `StartNew` was not relevant, but my point is:  thread pool is more sophisticated than I thought before and it does not necessary create new thread, even if there are no threads available and current busy threads number is less than minimum (so SetMinThreads does not have any effect in this case). It tries to maximize throughput (based on previous timings), and in this case throughput is better with low number of threads (because creating new thread is costly, and so if it created new thread every time there are no free threads available - the whole thing would take much more time).

Comment: My point above that "SetMinThreads does not have any effect" is false. Thread pool does obey min threads and will not invoke its algorithm until that number of threads is reached, I (and you I suppose) was just setting it wrong. It returns bool which indicates if change was actually applied. `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50000, 50000);` returns false. It seems max minimum number of threads you can set is `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(short.MaxValue, 1000);` (even after adjusting SetMaxThreads to bigger value). In that case it will indeed use 32767 threads which will completely destroy perfomance.

Comment: One last remark about `Task.Factory.StartNew(IoBoundWork, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`. It will indeed create 100000 threads but will do that quite slowly, so `for` loop will complete only in about 80 seconds (compared to 2 seconds for `Task.Run` case). Because of that, there will be no 100.000 concurrent threads, but actually relatively small number of concurrent threads, so thread pool will be able to handle await continuations just fine for them, and elapsed time of all watches will be very close to 1 second, with original OP code.

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is performance, `async-await` is the wrong solution.

`async-await` is all about availability. Availability to handle the screen and user impute, availability to handle HTTP requests, etc.

The synchronization work behind `async-await` will use more resources and take more time than simply blocking until the operation completes.

Your HTTP server will handle more requests because less threads will be blocked waiting for operations to complete but each request will take slightly longer.